# C# Modify UI from native thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, delegates, pinvoke

Let a form that contains a text box and a method to set it (in an unsafe way):

```
class Form
{
    void SetTextBoxContent( String txt )
    {
        this._tb_TextBox.SetText( txt );
    }
}
```

Now if i want to make this thread-safe, i need to do the following :

```
class Form
{
    void SetTextBoxContent( String txt )
    {
        if( this._tb_TextBox.InvokeRequired )
            this._tb_TextBox.Invoke( new DelegateSetTextBoxContentUnsafe( SetTextBoxContentUnsafe );
        else
            this.DelagSetTextBoxContentUnsafe( txt );
    }

    delegate void DelegateSetTextBoxContentUnsafe( String txt );

    void SetTextBoxContentUnsafe( String txt )
    {
        this._tb_TextBox.SetText( txt );
    }
}
```

Right ? Now what if i want to make calling SetTextBoxContent() from a native thread possible ? As far as i know there is no way of calling an object's methods, so instead i would pass a pointer to a static function into the native code. This function would have a reference to the Form object and perform the method call itself :

```
class Form
{
    static Form instance;

    Form() { Form.instance = this }

    static void CallSetTextBoxContent( String txt )
    {
        Form.instance.SetTextBoxContent( txt );
    }

    void SetTextBoxContent( String txt )
    {
        if( this._tb_TextBox.InvokeRequired )
            this._tb_TextBox.Invoke( new DelagSetTextBoxContentUnsafe( SetTextBoxContentUnsafe );
        else
            this.DelagSetTextBoxContentUnsafe( txt );
    }

    delegate void DelagSetTextBoxContentUnsafe( String txt );

    void SetTextBoxContentUnsafe( String txt )
    {
        this._tb_TextBox.SetText( txt );
    }
}
```

Now can I just pass my static function CallSetTextBoxContent() into the native code ?
I read somewhere that i need to create a delegate for this. So that means i need to create a second type of delegate for CallSetTextBoxContent() and pass this delegate to the native code ? 2 delegate types and 3 functions to do something that simple seems a bit messy. Is it the right way ?

Thank you :)

EDIT : Forgot to mention that i'm using compact framework 2.0

Comment: You don't have to create your own delegates. Use existing ones. `Action<string>` should match the signature of your method.

Comment: Thanks. Seems cleaner, but can this one be passed to native code ?

Comment: It is just like any other delegate. You can pass it to native code as you would do for other delegates.

Answer (score 1):

See [Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/at4fb09f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and an example here: [Sending callbacks from C# to C++](https://inphamousdevelopment.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/sending-callbacks-from-c-to-c/)

Comment: Thanks. Can i use the `IntPtr` i'm getting from this function as a regular function pointer in the native code ? I forgot to mention that i'm using standard unmanaged C++.

Comment: @Virus721 Yes, you can.

Comment: Ask yourself if it's wise to couple the UI and the unmanaged code in this way.

Comment: Using static things seems to be a bit dirty, but otherwise i don't see what is the problem with this. I did not mention it, but the same unmanaged code in also in use with Android and JNI, so i have several other constraints.